# ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None; doesn't work

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, listbox

ListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None; doesn't work

When I set this via Designer or code the list box acts as multi selection.  Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Short answer is `No`, please try to provide a complete example which demonstrates this issue, because there must be something else you are doing which is causing the `ListBox` to behave differently than you are expecting.

Comment: It is a bit clumsy.  It prevents your *code* from selecting an item.  But doesn't prevent the user from selecting one.  A listbox that doesn't allow selecting anything is a bit like a boomerang that doesn't come back.  It is a stick.  There are other ways to display lines of text.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant seems your right, while None does nothing to the UI, One and Multi affect how the UI works.  Seems pretty dumb that .None doesn't.  Was trying for a Read Only list box can't set Enable = false because then the user can't scroll. Am using the list box for a list of actions the program as taken like a log.  Can't use a Textbox for this because some lines are a different color and/or bolded.